# Can you liberate a city that you captured, via gifting to a third party?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civ5 I have read there is a process to capture a city and then trade it, recapture it, and then get a liberation bonus. What are the conditions for this. Is there a waiting period that the city must be held. Does it work for non capitals?

Comment: Could you describe what you imagine the end result to look like? I think you listed all the steps and the process is rather straightforward, though I'm not sure if you see what happens there

Comment: The end result for the player would be a liberation bonus and, by the world congress, free votes forever. Obviously, the third-party would need to be an enemy of some sort, so the player doesn't mind declaring war.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old, but yes, you can liberate it after conquering+gifting. You don't need to wait for it.
It also works for non-capitals. You just have to deal with the war mongering malus and other political consequences when declaring war to the third party.